# React tooltip (react-tooltip) throws 'ResizeObserver' error after upgrade

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip, react-resize-observer

**The context:** I recently upgraded the react-tooltip package to `"react-tooltip": "^5.26.0"` from `"react-tooltip": "4.2.11"`. I also made the required code changes according to the new props available on the component

My react version is: `"react": "17.0.2",`

**The Problem:** After the upgrade, when I run the app and hover over any component where the tooltip should appear, I get the following error

`ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications. at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:237280:58`

Is this a bug in the package or am I missing something?